# Vue + Firestore assign userGroup to Article and User to UserGroup

Tags: authentication, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, user-permissions

Not sure where to start with this one (and I looked far and wide for some help). Not even sure if I'm asking the right questions because I just can't find any docs or tutorials for this scenario. All I found and got working is login/auth with firebase firestore but nothing on groups > users > content. Maybe I'm searching the wrong terms.

I want to build an app in Vue with Firebase (Firestore). I want different companies to sign up and create user accounts once they sign up they can CRUD articles that they've created.

My Questions:

1) Is this structure for Firestore flat enough? Or is there a better approach?

```
Companies:
 - Company-1 > Can access Articles 1, 4 & 7
 - Company-2 > Can access Articles 6 & 9
 - Company-3 > Can access Articles 2, 3, 5 & 8


Users:
 - User-1 > Belongs to Company-1 (access Articles 1, 4 & 7)
 - User-2 > Belongs to Company-1 (access Articles 1, 4 & 7)
 - User-3 > Belongs to Company-1 (access Articles 1, 4 & 7)
 - User-4 > Belongs to Company-2 (access Articles 6 & 9)
 - User-5 > Belongs to Company-3 (access Articles 1, 4 & 7)
 - User-6 > Belongs to Company-1 (access Articles 1, 4 & 7)


Articles:
 - Article 1
 - Article 2
 - Article 3
 - Article 4
 - Article 5
 - Article 6
 - Article 7
 - Article 8
 - Article 9
```

---

JSON

```
        {
       "companies": 
          {
             "company1": {
            "canCRUD": "[atricleID_1, atricleID_4, atricleID_7]"
             },
             "company2": {
            "canCRUD": "[atricleID_2, atricleID_3, atricleID_5, atricleID_8]"
             },
             "company3": {
                "canCRUD": "[atricleID_6, atricleID_9]"
             }
          },
       "users": {
             "user_1": {
                "memberOfCompany": "company1",
                "uid": "123"
             },
             "user_2": {
                "memberOfCompany": "company1",
                "uid": "321"
             },
             "user_3": {
                "memberOfCompany": "company2",
                "uid": "132"
             },
             "user_4": {
                "memberOfCompany": "company2",
                "uid": "312"
             },
             "user_5": {
                "memberOfCompany": "company3",
                "uid": "213"
             }
          },
       "articles" :{
      "articleID_1": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "atricleID_2": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_3": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_4": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_5": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_6": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_7": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_8": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      },
      "articleID_9": {
         "atricleContent": "here..."
      }

       }
    }
```

2) Shall I handle the group/user roles/permissions with Vue/Vuex or Cloud functions?

If you can point me in the right direction; that would be awesome!

Comment: Can you pease edit your question to show your database schema in a JSON style?

Comment: @Alex Mamo - ok...

Comment: Looks good to me. Do you have issues when querying it?

Comment: Sweet! Yip you could say that I have problems with querying it. As in I have no idea how to do it. :D I've successfully created register/login by following the Firestore docs & Vue tutorials but how do I now go about assigning a user to a group & a group to a company & then a company to articles so that when you login you can only CRUD documents that belong to the group > company. Do I set it up in the DB rules, Cloud functions or in Vue with something like CASL? Sorry for the stupid questions - new to Vue as well as Firestore. Also need to setup super user to create companies/groups/users.